# Download 2 GB file in Service Fabric application

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am designing an application which will support upload and download of XML file with limit of 2 GBs. I am using Azure Blob Storage as persistent storage to upload these files and then download them. Below piece of code throws OutOfMemory exception :

```
 var blob = this.GetBlockBlobReference(blobId, blobContainerName);
 return await blob.DownloadTextAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Also, I am not sure which approach will be faster and cleaner.

Comment: Not surprising. *Don't* try to read the entire 2GB file at once in memory. This would be a bad idea in a desktop application, much less a cloud app. Use DownloadToFile or DownloadToStream instead. If the target is another block bloc, use StartCopy

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos DownloadToStream won't use memory? Also, would it be faster?

Comment: It won't *store* the entire file in memory, it will copy it to the target stream. And no, you can't use a MemoryStream for this, you'd end up with another 2GB-sized buffer. What are you trying to do in the first place? Different methods are used for different jobs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can we use DownloadToFile with parallel threads download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For faster downloading / uploading blobs, you can consider using 
[Microsoft Azure Storage Data Movement Library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement#microsoft-azure-storage-data-movement-library-110). This library is designed for high-performance uploading, downloading and copying Azure Storage Blob and File.

You can set parallel threads via code below:

```
// Setup the number of the concurrent operations
TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 64;
```

Then use `TransferManager.UploadAsync` or `TransferManager.DownloadAsync` method for uploading / downloading blobs respectively.

There is [an example in github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement#upload-a-blob) of uploading, you can modify it for downloading easily.